# Order of Markov Process

Tags: markov-process, information-theory

I ran across this problem in "Elements of Information theory", by Cover and Thomas:

A dog walks on the integers,
possibly reversing direction at each step with probability $$p = .1$$ Let $$X_0 = 0$$ The first step is equally likely to be positive or negative. A typical walk might look like this:

$$(X_0, X_1, . . .) = (0, −1, −2, −3, −4, −3, −2, −1, 0, 1, . . .)$$

Every discussion of this problem I've found states that this is a second order Markov process, but I can't see why. It seems to me that for i > 1 each state depends only on the one preceding it, so it should be an order 1 Markov process. What am I missing?

Comment: If I only tell you that the Markov chain is currently in state $n$, can you tell me the transition probabilities to states $n - 1$ and $n + 1$?

Comment: Alright, I got it, thanks. Seems very simple now, I don't know what I was thinking.